# CUDA kernel causing causing "display driver not responding" with the addition of 4 lines

Tags: c++, cuda

> The basic problem was as follows:
>
> When I run the below Kernel with N threads and **don't** include the 4
>   lines to instantiate and populate the ScaledLLA variable every thing
>   works fine.
>
> When I run the below Kernel with N threads and **do** include the 4
>   lines to instantiate and populate the ScaledLLA variable the GPU locks
>   up, and Windows throws a "display driver not responding" error.
>
> If I reduce the number of threads running by reducing the grid size
>   everything worked fine.

I'm new to CUDA and have been incrementally building out some GIS functionality.

my host code looks like this at the kernel call.

```
MapperKernel << <g_CUDAControl->aGetGridSize(), g_CUDAControl->aGetBlockSize() >> >(g_Deltas.lat, g_Deltas.lon, 32.2,
        g_DataReader->aGetMapper().aGetRPCBoundingBox()[0], g_DataReader->aGetMapper().aGetRPCBoundingBox()[1],
        g_CUDAControl->aGetBlockSize().x,
        g_CUDAControl->aGetThreadPitch(),
        LLA_Offset,
        LLA_ScaleFactor,
        RPC_XN,RPC_XD,RPC_YN,RPC_YD,
        Pixel_Offset, Pixel_ScaleFactor,
        device_array);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize(); //code crashes here
    host_array = (point3D*)malloc(num_bytes);
    cudaMemcpy(host_array, device_array, num_bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

the Kernel that is being called looks like this:

```
__global__ void MapperKernel(double deltaLat, double deltaLon, double passedAlt,
    double minLat, double minLon,
    int threadsperblock,
    int threadPitch,
    point3D LLA_Offset,
    point3D LLA_ScaleFactor,
    double * RPC_XN, double * RPC_XD, double * RPC_YN, double * RPC_YD,
    point2D pixelOffset, point2D pixelScaleFactor,
    point3D * rValue)
{
    //calculate thread's LLA
    int latindex = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*threadsperblock;
    int lonindex = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y*threadsperblock;
    point3D LLA;
    LLA.lat = ((double)(latindex))*deltaLat + minLat;
    LLA.lon = ((double)(lonindex))*deltaLon + minLon;
    LLA.alt = passedAlt;
    //scale threads LLA - adding these four lines is what causes the problem
    point3D ScaledLLA;
    ScaledLLA.lat = (LLA.lat - LLA_Offset.lat) * LLA_ScaleFactor.lat;
    ScaledLLA.lon = (LLA.lon - LLA_Offset.lon) * LLA_ScaleFactor.lon;
    ScaledLLA.alt = (LLA.alt - LLA_Offset.alt) * LLA_ScaleFactor.alt;

    rValue[lonindex*threadPitch + latindex] = ScaledLLA; //if I assign LLA without calculating ScaledLLA everything works fine
}
```

if I assign LLA to rValue then everything executes quickly and I get the expected behavior; however, when I add those fourlines for ScaledLLA and try to assign it to rValue, CUDA takes too long for windows's liking at the cudaDeviceSynchronize() call and I get a 
"display driver not responding" error that then proceeds to reset the GPU. From looking around the error appears to be a windows thing that occurs when Windows believes that the GPU isn't being responsive. I am certain that the kernel is running and performing the right calculations, because I have stepped through it with the NSIGHT debugger.

Does anybody have a good explanation for why adding those three lines to the kernel would cause the execution time to spike?

I'm running Win7 VS 2013 and have nsight 4.5 installed.

Comment: Answering this would require the shortest working example you can supply. It is very hard know what might be happening without compileable code. What GPU are you running this on?

Answer (score -2):

For those who get here later via a search engine. It turns out the problem was with the card running out of memory.

That should probably have been one of the top couple of things to think of since the problem occurred only after the instantiation was added.

The card only had so much memory (~2GB) and my rvalue buffer was taking up most (~1.5GB) of it. With every thread trying to instantiate its own point3D variable the card simply ran out of memory.

For those interested NSight's profiler said that it was a cudaUknownError.

> The fix was to lower the number of threads running the kernel

Comment: This explanation makes no sense whatsoever. Exhausting memory will never results in a "display driver not responding error". If you run the device completely out of resources, it will cause API and kernel launch failures. Those will never cause any GPU occupancy and will never trigger a driver reset. Something else was happening, and whatever you changes you made might have fixed it, but the root cause was not memory exhaustion. You never provided any repro case that could be properly analysed, so I guess you will never know what the problem was, until it happens again.

Comment: @talonmies sorry you feel that way. I bow to your vastly superior knowledge of what fixed my problem. and will in the future do whatever you say to make sure that I get my problems fixed in the way you deem most appropriate. Have fun trolling other post, or doing whatever you would call what your profile says " I spend most of my time editing, down-voting and closing rather than answering questions."